# Is "independent minded woman" a set phrase?

Tags: phrases, gender-politics

Is the phrase "independent minded woman" a set phrase which is used very frequently compared to an independent minded man or an independent minded person? If so, why?

I tried using Google ngrams, but the values were very low, possibly because of hyphenation issues.

Comment: Google Ngrams, as it so often does, provides a [curious result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=independent+minded+woman%2C+independent+minded+man&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindependent%20minded%20man%3B%2Cc0) *independent minded woman* produces nothing at all.

Comment: If you add a hyphen, you get that "independent-minded woman" is [twice as frequent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=independent-minded+woman%2C%5Bindependent+minded+man%5D%2B%5Bindependent-minded+man%5D&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindependent%20-%20minded%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%5Bindependent%20minded%20man%5D%20%2B%20%5Bindependent%20-%20minded%20man%5D%29%3B%2Cc0) as "independent-minded man".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting part of the question, I think, is in whether or not "an independent minded woman" is a **set phrase**.

Set, or fixed phrases are relatively immutable patterns of words that have taken on an idiomatic meaning, often bearing an intentional connotation peculiar to the expression.

While quantitative measures such as Ngrams can demonstrate frequency of occurrence, they cannot always point reliably either to intention or acceptance in current contexts.

With this caution in hand, I believe that "independent-minded woman" may have been a set phrase in the mid-20th century, at least in the US.  There, and at that time, it may have been a convenient euphemism, an ironic descriptor for a woman whose self-direction may have been at odds with then-accepted ideas of propriety.

I believe that "independent minded" has regained a measure of innocence in the light of new Western views of gender fairness, and that it can be applied with equal objectivity to women, men, persons, and shadings between.

*At least that's my independent-minded sense of it.*